# How does Stack Overflow include Javascript files?

Tags: javascript

I was looking at the SO source code to see how they are doing the div on the right side bar that changes from relative to fixed position.

I saw that the SO JS library is pretty much all included into the page with this code below...

My question is how is the code included like this, is this something like the [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) or [labJS](http://labjs.com/) javascript code that loads the files only when they are needed or something like that?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
StackExchange.using.setCacheBreakers({
    "js/prettify-full.js": "0324556b7bf7",
    "js/moderator.js": "a38ca3c6143d",
    "js/full-anon.js": "8fcefa158ad3",
    "js/full.js": "a168b3deac0f",
    "js/wmd.js": "688233b2af68",
    "js/third-party/jquery.autocomplete.min.js": "e5f01e97f7c3",
    "js/mobile.js": "97644ef9b7d4",
    "js/help.js": "7f83495f785a",
    "js/tageditor.js": "75954ba7b6f1",
    "js/tageditornew.js": "9d9998359a54",
    "js/inline-tag-editing.js": "364e12111b4b",
    "js/mathjax-editing.js": "a47e02eb0282",
    "js/revisions.js": "63c88065da1f"
});
</script>
```

Comment: Seems valid question to me

Comment: Have you already attempted to analyse the source code? http://jsbeautifier.org can be used to de-minify the code. Source code is available at http://cdn.sstatic.net/js/stub.js?v=e922af98260a. **De-minified code: http://pastebin.com/W5ynGRNS**

Comment: @Rob W Yes the code above is the  Beautified version, I am still learning Javascript so I can somewhat follow it but I do not know enough to realize what or how it is including the files

Comment: @Sarfraz Hello, that is what I thought, I tried to make it appropriate

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> My question is how is the code included like this, is this something like the RequireJS or labJS javascript code that loads the files only when they are needed or something like that?

Yes, but not one of the two – it's a very tiny home-grown solution. The snippet you posted just lets the JavaScript know what cache breakers to use *if* including a file; it doesn't actually include them. That only happens when the file is actually needed.

I wrote a [blog post](http://balpha.de/2011/10/jquery-script-insertion-and-its-consequences-for-debugging/) that gives some insight into what's happening there.

Comment: @balpha great! i'd like to use the "loadScript" function, is it copyrighted?

Comment: @shadesco: If anything, it's under the same license as jQuery (MIT/GPL at your choice), since that's where it comes from.